# How to integrate Worklight and IBM Lotus Notes database

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm looking for a solution where the need is to integrate a Worklight application to a Lotus Notes database. Currently the transaction and business data along with the workflow processes are stored in Lotus Notes DB.

The requirement is to understand the ability to integrate and pull transaction data from the Lotus Notes DB.

Please advice, if this can be simply achieved using the SQL Adapter mechanism in Worklight ?

Answer (score 1):

The technique shown in Mat Newman's presentation is a much better choice as it is using the more modern data interfaces into Notes.

The ODBC drivers are still around, but I haven't seen anybody using them in a while. For example, the IBM page for the ODBC driver says that you will need Windows 2000 XP or Windows Server 2003 to run them. As Notes is not a relational database, trying to access it as one was always a bit tricky.